# Смысл в php, если есть Vue.js

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Недавно начал изучать Vue.js. Дошёл до изучения vue-router. Как я понимаю он нужен для создания ЧПУ ссылок. Так же vue.js  умеет выводить элементы блога через цикл. И многое-многое другое. Вот в чём вопрос. В чём смысл php тогда, кроме работы с БД? Допустим хочу сделать блог. Стоит делать ЧПУ на vue или php?

Comment: Смысл в Феррари если есть Т40, есть разница получить 2к - html, или 10М скриптов ?

Comment: Вопрос поставлен неправильно. Правильный вопрос: смысл в vue.js, если есть php? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень странная постановка вопроса, ведь роуты можно настроить в том числе и через конфигурацию nginx, например. В данном вопросе нужно руководствоваться здравым смыслом и грамотной архитектурой приложения: поддерживать приложение роуты которого вынесены в php, будет невыносимо больно.

Я рекомендую не останавливаться на главе с роутами, а прочесть руководство полностью.

Добавлю, что Vue и другие фронтенд-фреймворки призваны помочь программисту построить так называемые SPA (Single Page Application), одно из преимуществ которых состоит в отсутствии перезагрузки, когда как использование системы роутов построеных срежствами php, будет требовать перезагрузки страницы, что как бы делает приложение уже не одностраничным.

Comment: Извините, что переспрашиваю. Но всё таки роуты лучше делать в vue?

Comment: Для отсутствия перезагрузки не обязательно делать SPA. При использовании php-роутов не обязательно делать перезагрузку страницы.

Comment: @ДимаСурок Да, лучше использовать Vue

Comment: @andreymal есть тысяча и один способ сделать что-то сложым.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗаварзин подключить pjax к сайту — легко и просто. :)